# What happened to GremCheck? Is there a viable replacement?

Tags: javascript, testing, functional-testing, user-acceptance-testing

I was a big fan of an app called "GremCheck" that was out a while back, that seems to have disappeared.

It was a JavaScript included in a master page that placed an icon at the bottom of the page. It was used during testing. You could define your own tests, and the box could pop up per page and viewers would answer the questions you define (such as "Does this page have the correct title?", "Is the Grammar Correct", "Does the design look consistent").

This was useful for end-user tests groups and quick testing for developers if time was squeezed on full functional testing.

Anyone know where GremCheck went, if I can get to it, and if there's anything out there that does something similar?

Comment: Try asking here :http://stackapps.com/

Comment: stackapps appears to be a community for the StackExchange API, which I'm not dealing with now. Is there a reason you wanted me to ask it there?

Comment: He probably meant http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ . But I doubt you'd get any answers there too, seeing it gets little exposure compared to StackOverflow